# regex для замены всех вхождений кроме вхождений внутри тега <a>

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В строке:

`Есть текст, где много красивых слов, словосочетаний и не только <a href="http://google.com/" > слов </a>.`

Нужно заменить "слов" на "букв" и получить:

`Есть текст, где много красивых букв, словосочетаний и не только <a href="http://google.com/" > слов </a>.`

Т.е. внутри тега `<a>` замена не должна быть.

Я пробовал как-то так:

```
preg_replace("/(?<!<a.*)слов(?!.*<\/a>)/ig", "букв", $text);
```

но не получается...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В регулярках PHP нет поддержки модификатора `g` (`preg_replace` производит замену всех совпадений по умолчанию, а для поисках всех совпадений в строке существует отдельная функция `preg_match_all`). Кроме того, шаблоны в блоках предварительного просмотра назад нельзя использовать шаблоны неизвестной длины (т.е. `(?<!<a.*)` нельзя использовать из-за квантификатора `*`, который находит 0 и более (неизвестно, сколько до начала поиска сопвпадения) символов).

Используйте

```
$text = "Есть текст, где много красивых слов, словосочетаний и не только <a href=\"http://google.com/\" > слов </a>.";
echo preg_replace("/<a\b[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)|слов/iu","букв",$text);
```

См. [PHP-демо](http://ideone.com/Cv4oIj)

**Подробности**:

- `<a\b[^>]*>[^<]*<\/a>(*SKIP)(*F)` - тег `<a>` (находится и удаляется из совпадения (т.е. "пропускается") с помощью `(*SKIP)(*F)`)
- `|` - или
- `слов` - последовательность буквальных символов `слов`

Comment: Круто! Я бы сам не додумался до  SKIP. Спасибо.